# What does 'Current affinity assignment is not ideal, it is waiting for cache' mean in Ignite logs?

Tags: ignite

I am currently trying to track down some intermittent issues on a shared Ignite cluster, and monitoring the logs.

I see large recurring log entries with "Current affinity assignment is not ideal, it is waiting for cache", and have not been able to find information on what this means.

Here is a complete sample log entry:

```
Current affinity assignment is not ideal, it is waiting for cache: grp=[grpId=-717246150, nodes=[node=[id=ee306c6b-2ee7-4d38-b6a6-93fc868c6939, partsNum=265], node=[id=40bebfd4-4333-4f36-885a-374b02b0a0e0, partsNum=265]]], grp=[grpId=706180381, nodes=[node=[id=ee306c6b-2ee7-4d38-b6a6-93fc868c6939, partsNum=495], node=[id=40bebfd4-4333-4f36-885a-374b02b0a0e0, partsNum=495]]], grp=[grpId=625062986, nodes=[node=[id=ee306c6b-2ee7-4d38-b6a6-93fc868c6939, partsNum=265], node=[id=40bebfd4-4333-4f36-885a-374b02b0a0e0, partsNum=265]]], grp=[grpId=-1078994526, nodes=[node=[id=ee306c6b-2ee7-4d38-b6a6-93fc868c6939, partsNum=495], node=[id=40bebfd4-4333-4f36-885a-374b02b0a0e0, partsNum=495]]], grp=[grpId=1165738614, nodes=[node=[id=ee306c6b-2ee7-4d38-b6a6-93fc868c6939, partsNum=265], node=[id=40bebfd4-4333-4f36-885a-374b02b0a0e0, partsNum=265]]], grp=[grpId=-1038824423, nodes=[node=[id=ee306c6b-2ee7-4d38-b6a6-93fc868c6939, partsNum=265], node=[id=40bebfd4-4333-4f36-885a-374b02b0a0e0, partsNum=265]]], grp=[grpId=1318860691, nodes=[node=[id=ee306c6b-2ee7-4d38-b6a6-93fc868c6939, partsNum=265], node=[id=40bebfd4-4333-4f36-885a-374b02b0a0e0, partsNum=265]]], grp=[grpId=-2047913985, nodes=[node=[id=ee306c6b-2ee7-4d38-b6a6-93fc868c6939, partsNum=265], node=[id=40bebfd4-4333-4f36-885a-374b02b0a0e0, partsNum=265]]], grp=[grpId=61396923, nodes=[node=[id=ee306c6b-2ee7-4d38-b6a6-93fc868c6939, partsNum=265], node=[id=40bebfd4-4333-4f36-885a-374b02b0a0e0, partsNum=265]]], grp=[grpId=341584719, nodes=[node=[id=ee306c6b-2ee7-4d38-b6a6-93fc868c6939, partsNum=265], node=[id=40bebfd4-4333-4f36-885a-374b02b0a0e0, partsNum=265]]], grp=[grpId=-243720337, nodes=[node=[id=ee306c6b-2ee7-4d38-b6a6-93fc868c6939, partsNum=265], node=[id=40bebfd4-4333-4f36-885a-374b02b0a0e0, partsNum=265]]], grp=[grpId=304434226, nodes=[node=[id=ee306c6b-2ee7-4d38-b6a6-93fc868c6939, partsNum=495], node=[id=40bebfd4-4333-4f36-885a-374b02b0a0e0, partsNum=495]]], grp=[grpId=-838283477, nodes=[node=[id=ee306c6b-2ee7-4d38-b6a6-93fc868c6939, partsNum=495], node=[id=40bebfd4-4333-4f36-885a-374b02b0a0e0, partsNum=495]]], grp=[grpId=-64291316, nodes=[node=[id=ee306c6b-2ee7-4d38-b6a6-93fc868c6939, partsNum=265], node=[id=40bebfd4-4333-4f36-885a-374b02b0a0e0, partsNum=265]]], grp=[grpId=711877703, nodes=[node=[id=ee306c6b-2ee7-4d38-b6a6-93fc868c6939, partsNum=265], node=[id=40bebfd4-4333-4f36-885a-374b02b0a0e0, partsNum=265]]], grp=[grpId=-1617381711, nodes=[node=[id=ee306c6b-2ee7-4d38-b6a6-93fc868c6939, partsNum=265], node=[id=40bebfd4-4333-4f36-885a-374b02b0a0e0, partsNum=265]]], grp=[grpId=-1178271505, nodes=[node=[id=ee306c6b-2ee7-4d38-b6a6-93fc868c6939, partsNum=265], node=[id=40bebfd4-4333-4f36-885a-374b02b0a0e0, partsNum=265]]], grp=[grpId=609060193, nodes=[node=[id=ee306c6b-2ee7-4d38-b6a6-93fc868c6939, partsNum=495], node=[id=40bebfd4-4333-4f36-885a-374b02b0a0e0, partsNum=495]]], grp=[grpId=-916506254, nodes=[node=[id=ee306c6b-2ee7-4d38-b6a6-93fc868c6939, partsNum=265], node=[id=40bebfd4-4333-4f36-885a-374b02b0a0e0, partsNum=265]]], grp=[grpId=-1760963292, nodes=[node=[id=ee306c6b-2ee7-4d38-b6a6-93fc868c6939, partsNum=265], node=[id=40bebfd4-4333-4f36-885a-374b02b0a0e0, partsNum=265]]], grp=[grpId=-388804612, nodes=[node=[id=ee306c6b-2ee7-4d38-b6a6-93fc868c6939, partsNum=495], node=[id=40bebfd4-4333-4f36-885a-374b02b0a0e0, partsNum=495]]], grp=[grpId=847127119, nodes=[node=[id=ee306c6b-2ee7-4d38-b6a6-93fc868c6939, partsNum=265], node=[id=40bebfd4-4333-4f36-885a-374b02b0a0e0, partsNum=265]]], grp=[grpId=289080072, nodes=[node=[id=ee306c6b-2ee7-4d38-b6a6-93fc868c6939, partsNum=265], node=[id=40bebfd4-4333-4f36-885a-374b02b0a0e0, partsNum=265]]], grp=[grpId=-985829106, nodes=[node=[id=ee306c6b-2ee7-4d38-b6a6-93fc868c6939, partsNum=265], node=[id=40bebfd4-4333-4f36-885a-374b02b0a0e0, partsNum=265]]], grp=[grpId=1831430941, nodes=[node=[id=ee306c6b-2ee7-4d38-b6a6-93fc868c6939, partsNum=265], node=[id=40bebfd4-4333-4f36-885a-374b02b0a0e0, partsNum=265]]], grp=[grpId=-2100569601, nodes=[node=[id=ee306c6b-2ee7-4d38-b6a6-93fc868c6939, partsNum=51], node=[id=40bebfd4-4333-4f36-885a-374b02b0a0e0, partsNum=51]]], grp=[grpId=127047844, nodes=[node=[id=ee306c6b-2ee7-4d38-b6a6-93fc868c6939, partsNum=265], node=[id=40bebfd4-4333-4f36-885a-374b02b0a0e0, partsNum=265]]], grp=[grpId=340207473, nodes=[node=[id=ee306c6b-2ee7-4d38-b6a6-93fc868c6939, partsNum=495], node=[id=40bebfd4-4333-4f36-885a-374b02b0a0e0, partsNum=495]]], grp=[grpId=1481540982, nodes=[node=[id=ee306c6b-2ee7-4d38-b6a6-93fc868c6939, partsNum=265], node=[id=40bebfd4-4333-4f36-885a-374b02b0a0e0, partsNum=265]]], grp=[grpId=1158475824, nodes=[node=[id=ee306c6b-2ee7-4d38-b6a6-93fc868c6939, partsNum=265], node=[id=40bebfd4-4333-4f36-885a-374b02b0a0e0, partsNum=265]]], grp=[grpId=589292835, nodes=[node=[id=ee306c6b-2ee7-4d38-b6a6-93fc868c6939, partsNum=265], node=[id=40bebfd4-4333-4f36-885a-374b02b0a0e0, partsNum=265]]], grp=[grpId=1342602297, nodes=[node=[id=ee306c6b-2ee7-4d38-b6a6-93fc868c6939, partsNum=265], node=[id=40bebfd4-4333-4f36-885a-374b02b0a0e0, partsNum=265]]], grp=[grpId=-116944072, nodes=[node=[id=ee306c6b-2ee7-4d38-b6a6-93fc868c6939, partsNum=265], node=[id=40bebfd4-4333-4f36-885a-374b02b0a0e0, partsNum=265]]], grp=[grpId=-1102546424, nodes=[node=[id=ee306c6b-2ee7-4d38-b6a6-93fc868c6939, partsNum=265], node=[id=40bebfd4-4333-4f36-885a-374b02b0a0e0, partsNum=265]]], grp=[grpId=-856947028, nodes=[node=[id=ee306c6b-2ee7-4d38-b6a6-93fc868c6939, partsNum=265], node=[id=40bebfd4-4333-4f36-885a-374b02b0a0e0, partsNum=265]]], grp=[grpId=-1826535065, nodes=[node=[id=ee306c6b-2ee7-4d38-b6a6-93fc868c6939, partsNum=265], node=[id=40bebfd4-4333-4f36-885a-374b02b0a0e0, partsNum=265]]], grp=[grpId=1842824604, nodes=[node=[id=ee306c6b-2ee7-4d38-b6a6-93fc868c6939, partsNum=495], node=[id=40bebfd4-4333-4f36-885a-374b02b0a0e0, partsNum=495]]], grp=[grpId=-310149432, nodes=[node=[id=ee306c6b-2ee7-4d38-b6a6-93fc868c6939, partsNum=265], node=[id=40bebfd4-4333-4f36-885a-374b02b0a0e0, partsNum=265]]], grp=[grpId=420927323, nodes=[node=[id=ee306c6b-2ee7-4d38-b6a6-93fc868c6939, partsNum=265], node=[id=40bebfd4-4333-4f36-885a-374b02b0a0e0, partsNum=265]]], grp=[grpId=-1996702543, nodes=[node=[id=ee306c6b-2ee7-4d38-b6a6-93fc868c6939, partsNum=265], node=[id=40bebfd4-4333-4f36-885a-374b02b0a0e0, partsNum=265]]], grp=[grpId=225249571, nodes=[node=[id=ee306c6b-2ee7-4d38-b6a6-93fc868c6939, partsNum=495], node=[id=40bebfd4-4333-4f36-885a-374b02b0a0e0, partsNum=495]]], grp=[grpId=-1425879470, nodes=[node=[id=ee306c6b-2ee7-4d38-b6a6-93fc868c6939, partsNum=265], node=[id=40bebfd4-4333-4f36-885a-374b02b0a0e0, partsNum=265]]], grp=[grpId=1465461001, nodes=[node=[id=ee306c6b-2ee7-4d38-b6a6-93fc868c6939, partsNum=265], node=[id=40bebfd4-4333-4f36-885a-374b02b0a0e0, partsNum=265]]], grp=[grpId=728446526, nodes=[node=[id=ee306c6b-2ee7-4d38-b6a6-93fc868c6939, partsNum=265], node=[id=40bebfd4-4333-4f36-885a-374b02b0a0e0, partsNum=265]]], grp=[grpId=1716640007, nodes=[node=[id=ee306c6b-2ee7-4d38-b6a6-93fc868c6939, partsNum=495], node=[id=40bebfd4-4333-4f36-885a-374b02b0a0e0, partsNum=495]]], grp=[grpId=-1540006813, nodes=[node=[id=ee306c6b-2ee7-4d38-b6a6-93fc868c6939, partsNum=265], node=[id=40bebfd4-4333-4f36-885a-374b02b0a0e0, partsNum=265]]], grp=[grpId=-1354567660, nodes=[node=[id=ee306c6b-2ee7-4d38-b6a6-93fc868c6939, partsNum=265], node=[id=40bebfd4-4333-4f36-885a-374b02b0a0e0, partsNum=265]]], grp=[grpId=-446728183, nodes=[node=[id=ee306c6b-2ee7-4d38-b6a6-93fc868c6939, partsNum=265], node=[id=40bebfd4-4333-4f36-885a-374b02b0a0e0, partsNum=265]]], grp=[grpId=-515033835, nodes=[node=[id=ee306c6b-2ee7-4d38-b6a6-93fc868c6939, partsNum=265], node=[id=40bebfd4-4333-4f36-885a-374b02b0a0e0, partsNum=265]]], grp=[grpId=-2008616674, nodes=[node=[id=ee306c6b-2ee7-4d38-b6a6-93fc868c6939, partsNum=265], node=[id=40bebfd4-4333-4f36-885a-374b02b0a0e0, partsNum=265]]], grp=[grpId=815171020, nodes=[node=[id=ee306c6b-2ee7-4d38-b6a6-93fc868c6939, partsNum=265], node=[id=40bebfd4-4333-4f36-885a-374b02b0a0e0, partsNum=265]]], grp=[grpId=-919975311, nodes=[node=[id=ee306c6b-2ee7-4d38-b6a6-93fc868c6939, partsNum=265], node=[id=40bebfd4-4333-4f36-885a-374b02b0a0e0, partsNum=265]]], grp=[grpId=-602303422, nodes=[node=[id=ee306c6b-2ee7-4d38-b6a6-93fc868c6939, partsNum=265], node=[id=40bebfd4-4333-4f36-885a-374b02b0a0e0, partsNum=265]]], grp=[grpId=1505411815, nodes=[node=[id=ee306c6b-2ee7-4d38-b6a6-93fc868c6939, partsNum=265], node=[id=40bebfd4-4333-4f36-885a-374b02b0a0e0, partsNum=265]]], grp=[grpId=-1115387686, nodes=[node=[id=ee306c6b-2ee7-4d38-b6a6-93fc868c6939, partsNum=265], node=[id=40bebfd4-4333-4f36-885a-374b02b0a0e0, partsNum=265]]], grp=[grpId=-103452790, nodes=[node=[id=ee306c6b-2ee7-4d38-b6a6-93fc868c6939, partsNum=265], node=[id=40bebfd4-4333-4f36-885a-374b02b0a0e0, partsNum=265]]], grp=[grpId=275636530, nodes=[node=[id=ee306c6b-2ee7-4d38-b6a6-93fc868c6939, partsNum=265], node=[id=40bebfd4-4333-4f36-885a-374b02b0a0e0, partsNum=265]]], grp=[grpId=-23082241, nodes=[node=[id=ee306c6b-2ee7-4d38-b6a6-93fc868c6939, partsNum=265], node=[id=40bebfd4-4333-4f36-885a-374b02b0a0e0, partsNum=265]]], grp=[grpId=1327621441, nodes=[node=[id=ee306c6b-2ee7-4d38-b6a6-93fc868c6939, partsNum=495], node=[id=40bebfd4-4333-4f36-885a-374b02b0a0e0, partsNum=495]]], grp=[grpId=487827825, nodes=[node=[id=ee306c6b-2ee7-4d38-b6a6-93fc868c6939, partsNum=265], node=[id=40bebfd4-4333-4f36-885a-374b02b0a0e0, partsNum=265]]], grp=[grpId=871963034, nodes=[node=[id=ee306c6b-2ee7-4d38-b6a6-93fc868c6939, partsNum=265], node=[id=40bebfd4-4333-4f36-885a-374b02b0a0e0, partsNum=265]]], grp=[grpId=498299095, nodes=[node=[id=ee306c6b-2ee7-4d38-b6a6-93fc868c6939, partsNum=265], node=[id=40bebfd4-4333-4f36-885a-374b02b0a0e0, partsNum=265]]], grp=[grpId=-2078309765, nodes=[node=[id=ee306c6b-2ee7-4d38-b6a6-93fc868c6939, partsNum=265], node=[id=40bebfd4-4333-4f36-885a-374b02b0a0e0, partsNum=265]]], grp=[grpId=1217149160, nodes=[node=[id=ee306c6b-2ee7-4d38-b6a6-93fc868c6939, partsNum=265], node=[id=40bebfd4-4333-4f36-885a-374b02b0a0e0, partsNum=265]]], grp=[grpId=-833824214, nodes=[node=[id=ee306c6b-2ee7-4d38-b6a6-93fc868c6939, partsNum=265], node=[id=40bebfd4-4333-4f36-885a-374b02b0a0e0, partsNum=265]]], grp=[grpId=-998203417, nodes=[node=[id=ee306c6b-2ee7-4d38-b6a6-93fc868c6939, partsNum=265], node=[id=40bebfd4-4333-4f36-885a-374b02b0a0e0, partsNum=265]]], grp=[grpId=-373344298, nodes=[node=[id=ee306c6b-2ee7-4d38-b6a6-93fc868c6939, partsNum=265], node=[id=40bebfd4-4333-4f36-885a-374b02b0a0e0, partsNum=265]]], grp=[grpId=-1172233651, nodes=[node=[id=ee306c6b-2ee7-4d38-b6a6-93fc868c6939, partsNum=265], node=[id=40bebfd4-4333-4f36-885a-374b02b0a0e0, partsNum=265]]], grp=[grpId=-732112847, nodes=[node=[id=ee306c6b-2ee7-4d38-b6a6-93fc868c6939, partsNum=265], node=[id=40bebfd4-4333-4f36-885a-374b02b0a0e0, partsNum=265]]], grp=[grpId=-809154895, nodes=[node=[id=ee306c6b-2ee7-4d38-b6a6-93fc868c6939, partsNum=265], node=[id=40bebfd4-4333-4f36-885a-374b02b0a0e0, partsNum=265]]], grp=[grpId=-1612401263, nodes=[node=[id=ee306c6b-2ee7-4d38-b6a6-93fc868c6939, partsNum=265], node=[id=40bebfd4-4333-4f36-885a-374b02b0a0e0, partsNum=265]]], grp=[grpId=244092409, nodes=[node=[id=ee306c6b-2ee7-4d38-b6a6-93fc868c6939, partsNum=265], node=[id=40bebfd4-4333-4f36-885a-374b02b0a0e0, partsNum=265]]], grp=[grpId=-461632247, nodes=[node=[id=ee306c6b-2ee7-4d38-b6a6-93fc868c6939, partsNum=265], node=[id=40bebfd4-4333-4f36-885a-374b02b0a0e0, partsNum=265]]], grp=[grpId=110417377, nodes=[node=[id=ee306c6b-2ee7-4d38-b6a6-93fc868c6939, partsNum=265], node=[id=40bebfd4-4333-4f36-885a-374b02b0a0e0, partsNum=265]]], grp=[grpId=2096437632, nodes=[node=[id=ee306c6b-2ee7-4d38-b6a6-93fc868c6939, partsNum=265], node=[id=40bebfd4-4333-4f36-885a-374b02b0a0e0, partsNum=265]]], grp=[grpId=-523074907, nodes=[node=[id=ee306c6b-2ee7-4d38-b6a6-93fc868c6939, partsNum=265], node=[id=40bebfd4-4333-4f36-885a-374b02b0a0e0, partsNum=265]]], grp=[grpId=192901639, nodes=[node=[id=ee306c6b-2ee7-4d38-b6a6-93fc868c6939, partsNum=265], node=[id=40bebfd4-4333-4f36-885a-374b02b0a0e0, partsNum=265]]], grp=[grpId=-1689619405, nodes=[node=[id=ee306c6b-2ee7-4d38-b6a6-93fc868c6939, partsNum=265], node=[id=40bebfd4-4333-4f36-885a-374b02b0a0e0, partsNum=265]]], grp=[grpId=2081466219, nodes=[node=[id=ee306c6b-2ee7-4d38-b6a6-93fc868c6939, partsNum=265], node=[id=40bebfd4-4333-4f36-885a-374b02b0a0e0, partsNum=265]]], grp=[grpId=-1532033580, nodes=[node=[id=ee306c6b-2ee7-4d38-b6a6-93fc868c6939, partsNum=265], node=[id=40bebfd4-4333-4f36-885a-374b02b0a0e0, partsNum=265]]], grp=[grpId=-765215971, nodes=[node=[id=ee306c6b-2ee7-4d38-b6a6-93fc868c6939, partsNum=265], node=[id=40bebfd4-4333-4f36-885a-374b02b0a0e0, partsNum=265]]], grp=[grpId=556559187, nodes=[node=[id=ee306c6b-2ee7-4d38-b6a6-93fc868c6939, partsNum=265], node=[id=40bebfd4-4333-4f36-885a-374b02b0a0e0, partsNum=265]]], grp=[grpId=1635868160, nodes=[node=[id=ee306c6b-2ee7-4d38-b6a6-93fc868c6939, partsNum=265], node=[id=40bebfd4-4333-4f36-885a-374b02b0a0e0, partsNum=265]]], grp=[grpId=-60477468, nodes=[node=[id=ee306c6b-2ee7-4d38-b6a6-93fc868c6939, partsNum=265], node=[id=40bebfd4-4333-4f36-885a-374b02b0a0e0, partsNum=265]]], grp=[grpId=-2091991859, nodes=[node=[id=ee306c6b-2ee7-4d38-b6a6-93fc868c6939, partsNum=495], node=[id=40bebfd4-4333-4f36-885a-374b02b0a0e0, partsNum=495]]], grp=[grpId=-2111756123, nodes=[node=[id=ee306c6b-2ee7-4d38-b6a6-93fc868c6939, partsNum=265], node=[id=40bebfd4-4333-4f36-885a-374b02b0a0e0, partsNum=265]]], grp=[grpId=919264077, nodes=[node=[id=ee306c6b-2ee7-4d38-b6a6-93fc868c6939, partsNum=495], node=[id=40bebfd4-4333-4f36-885a-374b02b0a0e0, partsNum=495]]], grp=[grpId=-1080634854, nodes=[node=[id=ee306c6b-2ee7-4d38-b6a6-93fc868c6939, partsNum=495], node=[id=40bebfd4-4333-4f36-885a-374b02b0a0e0, partsNum=495]]], grp=[grpId=1393703580, nodes=[node=[id=ee306c6b-2ee7-4d38-b6a6-93fc868c6939, partsNum=265], node=[id=40bebfd4-4333-4f36-885a-374b02b0a0e0, partsNum=265]]], grp=[grpId=-649517625, nodes=[node=[id=ee306c6b-2ee7-4d38-b6a6-93fc868c6939, partsNum=265], node=[id=40bebfd4-4333-4f36-885a-374b02b0a0e0, partsNum=265]]], grp=[grpId=-1881805734, nodes=[node=[id=ee306c6b-2ee7-4d38-b6a6-93fc868c6939, partsNum=265], node=[id=40bebfd4-4333-4f36-885a-374b02b0a0e0, partsNum=265]]], grp=[grpId=-2054664185, nodes=[node=[id=ee306c6b-2ee7-4d38-b6a6-93fc868c6939, partsNum=265], node=[id=40bebfd4-4333-4f36-885a-374b02b0a0e0, partsNum=265]]], grp=[grpId=-709223627, nodes=[node=[id=ee306c6b-2ee7-4d38-b6a6-93fc868c6939, partsNum=265], node=[id=40bebfd4-4333-4f36-885a-374b02b0a0e0, partsNum=265]]], grp=[grpId=860183765, nodes=[node=[id=ee306c6b-2ee7-4d38-b6a6-93fc868c6939, partsNum=495], node=[id=40bebfd4-4333-4f36-885a-374b02b0a0e0, partsNum=495]]], grp=[grpId=-364377380, nodes=[node=[id=ee306c6b-2ee7-4d38-b6a6-93fc868c6939, partsNum=265], node=[id=40bebfd4-4333-4f36-885a-374b02b0a0e0, partsNum=265]]], grp=[grpId=1999293375, nodes=[node=[id=ee306c6b-2ee7-4d38-b6a6-93fc868c6939, partsNum=265], node=[id=40bebfd4-4333-4f36-885a-374b02b0a0e0, partsNum=265]]], grp=[grpId=781314822, nodes=[node=[id=ee306c6b-2ee7-4d38-b6a6-93fc868c6939, partsNum=265], node=[id=40bebfd4-4333-4f36-885a-374b02b0a0e0, partsNum=265]]], grp=[grpId=767962193, nodes=[node=[id=ee306c6b-2ee7-4d38-b6a6-93fc868c6939, partsNum=265], node=[id=40bebfd4-4333-4f36-885a-374b02b0a0e0, partsNum=265]]], grp=[grpId=-562243355, nodes=[node=[id=ee306c6b-2ee7-4d38-b6a6-93fc868c6939, partsNum=265], node=[id=40bebfd4-4333-4f36-885a-374b02b0a0e0, partsNum=265]]], grp=[grpId=1230745793, nodes=[node=[id=ee306c6b-2ee7-4d38-b6a6-93fc868c6939, partsNum=265], node=[id=40bebfd4-4333-4f36-885a-374b02b0a0e0, partsNum=265]]], grp=[grpId=-1582572233, nodes=[node=[id=ee306c6b-2ee7-4d38-b6a6-93fc868c6939, partsNum=265], node=[id=40bebfd4-4333-4f36-885a-374b02b0a0e0, partsNum=265]]], grp=[grpId=-531928363, nodes=[node=[id=ee306c6b-2ee7-4d38-b6a6-93fc868c6939, partsNum=265], node=[id=40bebfd4-4333-4f36-885a-374b02b0a0e0, partsNum=265]]], grp=[grpId=-1929701029, nodes=[node=[id=ee306c6b-2ee7-4d38-b6a6-93fc868c6939, partsNum=265], node=[id=40bebfd4-4333-4f36-885a-374b02b0a0e0, partsNum=265]]], grp=[grpId=-1209475768, nodes=[node=[id=ee306c6b-2ee7-4d38-b6a6-93fc868c6939, partsNum=265], node=[id=40bebfd4-4333-4f36-885a-374b02b0a0e0, partsNum=265]]], grp=[grpId=785267055, nodes=[node=[id=ee306c6b-2ee7-4d38-b6a6-93fc868c6939, partsNum=495], node=[id=40bebfd4-4333-4f36-885a-374b02b0a0e0, partsNum=495]]], grp=[grpId=1994129273, nodes=[node=[id=ee306c6b-2ee7-4d38-b6a6-93fc868c6939, partsNum=495], node=[id=40bebfd4-4333-4f36-885a-374b02b0a0e0, partsNum=495]]], grp=[grpId=343330004, nodes=[node=[id=ee306c6b-2ee7-4d38-b6a6-93fc868c6939, partsNum=265], node=[id=40bebfd4-4333-4f36-885a-374b02b0a0e0, partsNum=265]]], grp=[grpId=-1225509806, nodes=[node=[id=ee306c6b-2ee7-4d38-b6a6-93fc868c6939, partsNum=265], node=[id=40bebfd4-4333-4f36-885a-374b02b0a0e0, partsNum=265]]], grp=[grpId=1048527833, nodes=[node=[id=ee306c6b-2ee7-4d38-b6a6-93fc868c6939, partsNum=265], node=[id=40bebfd4-4333-4f36-885a-374b02b0a0e0, partsNum=265]]], grp=[grpId=-1241379672, nodes=[node=[id=ee306c6b-2ee7-4d38-b6a6-93fc868c6939, partsNum=265], node=[id=40bebfd4-4333-4f36-885a-374b02b0a0e0, partsNum=265]]], grp=[grpId=1141157551, nodes=[node=[id=ee306c6b-2ee7-4d38-b6a6-93fc868c6939, partsNum=265], node=[id=40bebfd4-4333-4f36-885a-374b02b0a0e0, partsNum=265]]], grp=[grpId=-1700549364, nodes=[node=[id=ee306c6b-2ee7-4d38-b6a6-93fc868c6939, partsNum=265], node=[id=40bebfd4-4333-4f36-885a-374b02b0a0e0, partsNum=265]]], grp=[grpId=-502671431, nodes=[node=[id=ee306c6b-2ee7-4d38-b6a6-93fc868c6939, partsNum=265], node=[id=40bebfd4-4333-4f36-885a-374b02b0a0e0, partsNum=265]]], grp=[grpId=-1932464798, nodes=[node=[id=ee306c6b-2ee7-4d38-b6a6-93fc868c6939, partsNum=265], node=[id=40bebfd4-4333-4f36-885a-374b02b0a0e0, partsNum=265]]], grp=[grpId=-229645061, nodes=[node=[id=ee306c6b-2ee7-4d38-b6a6-93fc868c6939, partsNum=265], node=[id=40bebfd4-4333-4f36-885a-374b02b0a0e0, partsNum=265]]], grp=[grpId=1686071498, nodes=[node=[id=ee306c6b-2ee7-4d38-b6a6-93fc868c6939, partsNum=265], node=[id=40bebfd4-4333-4f36-885a-374b02b0a0e0, partsNum=265]]], grp=[grpId=1675814231, nodes=[node=[id=ee306c6b-2ee7-4d38-b6a6-93fc868c6939, partsNum=495], node=[id=40bebfd4-4333-4f36-885a-374b02b0a0e0, partsNum=495]]], grp=[grpId=2095119704, nodes=[node=[id=ee306c6b-2ee7-4d38-b6a6-93fc868c6939, partsNum=495], node=[id=40bebfd4-4333-4f36-885a-374b02b0a0e0, partsNum=495]]], grp=[grpId=1083932448, nodes=[node=[id=ee306c6b-2ee7-4d38-b6a6-93fc868c6939, partsNum=495], node=[id=40bebfd4-4333-4f36-885a-374b02b0a0e0, partsNum=495]]], grp=[grpId=1269522709, nodes=[node=[id=ee306c6b-2ee7-4d38-b6a6-93fc868c6939, partsNum=265], node=[id=40bebfd4-4333-4f36-885a-374b02b0a0e0, partsNum=265]]], grp=[grpId=-1593030990, nodes=[node=[id=ee306c6b-2ee7-4d38-b6a6-93fc868c6939, partsNum=265], node=[id=40bebfd4-4333-4f36-885a-374b02b0a0e0, partsNum=265]]], grp=[grpId=1940710674, nodes=[node=[id=ee306c6b-2ee7-4d38-b6a6-93fc868c6939, partsNum=265], node=[id=40bebfd4-4333-4f36-885a-374b02b0a0e0, partsNum=265]]], grp=[grpId=-980090069, nodes=[node=[id=ee306c6b-2ee7-4d38-b6a6-93fc868c6939, partsNum=265], node=[id=40bebfd4-4333-4f36-885a-374b02b0a0e0, partsNum=265]]], grp=[grpId=1763091156, nodes=[node=[id=ee306c6b-2ee7-4d38-b6a6-93fc868c6939, partsNum=265], node=[id=40bebfd4-4333-4f36-885a-374b02b0a0e0, partsNum=265]]], grp=[grpId=1677582392, nodes=[node=[id=ee306c6b-2ee7-4d38-b6a6-93fc868c6939, partsNum=495], node=[id=40bebfd4-4333-4f36-885a-374b02b0a0e0, partsNum=495]]], grp=[grpId=-1938862683, nodes=[node=[id=ee306c6b-2ee7-4d38-b6a6-93fc868c6939, partsNum=265], node=[id=40bebfd4-4333-4f36-885a-374b02b0a0e0, partsNum=265]]], grp=[grpId=-901517688, nodes=[node=[id=ee306c6b-2ee7-4d38-b6a6-93fc868c6939, partsNum=265], node=[id=40bebfd4-4333-4f36-885a-374b02b0a0e0, partsNum=265]]], grp=[grpId=447829601, nodes=[node=[id=ee306c6b-2ee7-4d38-b6a6-93fc868c6939, partsNum=265], node=[id=40bebfd4-4333-4f36-885a-374b02b0a0e0, partsNum=265]]], grp=[grpId=1869636512, nodes=[node=[id=ee306c6b-2ee7-4d38-b6a6-93fc868c6939, partsNum=265], node=[id=40bebfd4-4333-4f36-885a-374b02b0a0e0, partsNum=265]]], grp=[grpId=556221430, nodes=[node=[id=ee306c6b-2ee7-4d38-b6a6-93fc868c6939, partsNum=495], node=[id=40bebfd4-4333-4f36-885a-374b02b0a0e0, partsNum=495]]], grp=[grpId=2079328547, nodes=[node=[id=ee306c6b-2ee7-4d38-b6a6-93fc868c6939, partsNum=495], node=[id=40bebfd4-4333-4f36-885a-374b02b0a0e0, partsNum=495]]], grp=[grpId=-502372387, nodes=[node=[id=ee306c6b-2ee7-4d38-b6a6-93fc868c6939, partsNum=495], node=[id=40bebfd4-4333-4f36-885a-374b02b0a0e0, partsNum=495]]], grp=[grpId=-635173392, nodes=[node=[id=ee306c6b-2ee7-4d38-b6a6-93fc868c6939, partsNum=495], node=[id=40bebfd4-4333-4f36-885a-374b02b0a0e0, partsNum=495]]], grp=[grpId=-977982622, nodes=[node=[id=ee306c6b-2ee7-4d38-b6a6-93fc868c6939, partsNum=495], node=[id=40bebfd4-4333-4f36-885a-374b02b0a0e0, partsNum=495]]], grp=[grpId=1273818164, nodes=[node=[id=ee306c6b-2ee7-4d38-b6a6-93fc868c6939, partsNum=265], node=[id=40bebfd4-4333-4f36-885a-374b02b0a0e0, partsNum=265]]], grp=[grpId=1481402517, nodes=[node=[id=ee306c6b-2ee7-4d38-b6a6-93fc868c6939, partsNum=495], node=[id=40bebfd4-4333-4f36-885a-374b02b0a0e0, partsNum=495]]], grp=[grpId=-1439193363, nodes=[node=[id=ee306c6b-2ee7-4d38-b6a6-93fc868c6939, partsNum=495], node=[id=40bebfd4-4333-4f36-885a-374b02b0a0e0, partsNum=495]]], grp=[grpId=749895785, nodes=[node=[id=ee306c6b-2ee7-4d38-b6a6-93fc868c6939, partsNum=265], node=[id=40bebfd4-4333-4f36-885a-374b02b0a0e0, partsNum=265]]], grp=[grpId=138551198, nodes=[node=[id=ee306c6b-2ee7-4d38-b6a6-93fc868c6939, partsNum=265], node=[id=40bebfd4-4333-4f36-885a-374b02b0a0e0, partsNum=265]]], grp=[grpId=1013927821, nodes=[node=[id=ee306c6b-2ee7-4d38-b6a6-93fc868c6939, partsNum=265], node=[id=40bebfd4-4333-4f36-885a-374b02b0a0e0, partsNum=265]]], grp=[grpId=1967187362, nodes=[node=[id=ee306c6b-2ee7-4d38-b6a6-93fc868c6939, partsNum=265], node=[id=40bebfd4-4333-4f36-885a-374b02b0a0e0, partsNum=265]]], grp=[grpId=101519854, nodes=[node=[id=ee306c6b-2ee7-4d38-b6a6-93fc868c6939, partsNum=265], node=[id=40bebfd4-4333-4f36-885a-374b02b0a0e0, partsNum=265]]], grp=[grpId=990419437, nodes=[node=[id=ee306c6b-2ee7-4d38-b6a6-93fc868c6939, partsNum=265], node=[id=40bebfd4-4333-4f36-885a-374b02b0a0e0, partsNum=265]]], grp=[grpId=-1004449082, nodes=[node=[id=ee306c6b-2ee7-4d38-b6a6-93fc868c6939, partsNum=265], node=[id=40bebfd4-4333-4f36-885a-374b02b0a0e0, partsNum=265]]], grp=[grpId=1327857868, nodes=[node=[id=ee306c6b-2ee7-4d38-b6a6-93fc868c6939, partsNum=265], node=[id=40bebfd4-4333-4f36-885a-374b02b0a0e0, partsNum=265]]], grp=[grpId=-1572433236, nodes=[node=[id=ee306c6b-2ee7-4d38-b6a6-93fc868c6939, partsNum=265], node=[id=40bebfd4-4333-4f36-885a-374b02b0a0e0, partsNum=265]]], grp=[grpId=1243411447, nodes=[node=[id=ee306c6b-2ee7-4d38-b6a6-93fc868c6939, partsNum=265], node=[id=40bebfd4-4333-4f36-885a-374b02b0a0e0, partsNum=265]]], grp=[grpId=-599220060, nodes=[node=[id=ee306c6b-2ee7-4d38-b6a6-93fc868c6939, partsNum=265], node=[id=40bebfd4-4333-4f36-885a-374b02b0a0e0, partsNum=265]]], grp=[grpId=1523526946, nodes=[node=[id=ee306c6b-2ee7-4d38-b6a6-93fc868c6939, partsNum=265], node=[id=40bebfd4-4333-4f36-885a-374b02b0a0e0, partsNum=265]]], grp=[grpId=249864459, nodes=[node=[id=ee306c6b-2ee7-4d38-b6a6-93fc868c6939, partsNum=265], node=[id=40bebfd4-4333-4f36-885a-374b02b0a0e0, partsNum=265]]], grp=[grpId=1159164664, nodes=[node=[id=ee306c6b-2ee7-4d38-b6a6-93fc868c6939, partsNum=265], node=[id=40bebfd4-4333-4f36-885a-374b02b0a0e0, partsNum=265]]], grp=[grpId=-921774082, nodes=[node=[id=ee306c6b-2ee7-4d38-b6a6-93fc868c6939, partsNum=265], node=[id=40bebfd4-4333-4f36-885a-374b02b0a0e0, partsNum=265]]], grp=[grpId=813336200, nodes=[node=[id=ee306c6b-2ee7-4d38-b6a6-93fc868c6939, partsNum=265], node=[id=40bebfd4-4333-4f36-885a-374b02b0a0e0, partsNum=265]]], grp=[grpId=-1298541205, nodes=[node=[id=ee306c6b-2ee7-4d38-b6a6-93fc868c6939, partsNum=495], node=[id=40bebfd4-4333-4f36-885a-374b02b0a0e0, partsNum=495]]], grp=[grpId=686900482, nodes=[node=[id=ee306c6b-2ee7-4d38-b6a6-93fc868c6939, partsNum=265], node=[id=40bebfd4-4333-4f36-885a-374b02b0a0e0, partsNum=265]]], grp=[grpId=277160573, nodes=[node=[id=ee306c6b-2ee7-4d38-b6a6-93fc868c6939, partsNum=265], node=[id=40bebfd4-4333-4f36-885a-374b02b0a0e0, partsNum=265]]], grp=[grpId=-2029415184, nodes=[node=[id=ee306c6b-2ee7-4d38-b6a6-93fc868c6939, partsNum=265], node=[id=40bebfd4-4333-4f36-885a-374b02b0a0e0, partsNum=265]]], grp=[grpId=-124010398, nodes=[node=[id=ee306c6b-2ee7-4d38-b6a6-93fc868c6939, partsNum=265], node=[id=40bebfd4-4333-4f36-885a-374b02b0a0e0, partsNum=265]]], grp=[grpId=-804185621, nodes=[node=[id=ee306c6b-2ee7-4d38-b6a6-93fc868c6939, partsNum=265], node=[id=40bebfd4-4333-4f36-885a-374b02b0a0e0, partsNum=265]]], grp=[grpId=-1261387987, nodes=[node=[id=ee306c6b-2ee7-4d38-b6a6-93fc868c6939, partsNum=265], node=[id=40bebfd4-4333-4f36-885a-374b02b0a0e0, partsNum=265]]], grp=[grpId=1157840637, nodes=[node=[id=ee306c6b-2ee7-4d38-b6a6-93fc868c6939, partsNum=265], node=[id=40bebfd4-4333-4f36-885a-374b02b0a0e0, partsNum=265]]], grp=[grpId=823607273, nodes=[node=[id=ee306c6b-2ee7-4d38-b6a6-93fc868c6939, partsNum=265], node=[id=40bebfd4-4333-4f36-885a-374b02b0a0e0, partsNum=265]]], grp=[grpId=-1394283237, nodes=[node=[id=ee306c6b-2ee7-4d38-b6a6-93fc868c6939, partsNum=265], node=[id=40bebfd4-4333-4f36-885a-374b02b0a0e0, partsNum=265]]]
```

Can anyone clarify that this log entry means?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This message is printed in a log of a current coordinator. It basically means that the cluster contains partitions that haven't yet been [rebalanced](https://www.gridgain.com/docs/latest/developers-guide/data-rebalancing#data-rebalancing) and data is not fully distributed accordingly to the [affinity function](https://www.gridgain.com/docs/latest/developers-guide/data-modeling/data-partitioning#affinity-function).